# How do I read what's been selected in a MULTIPLE listbox

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I'm very new to Python and can't get my head round how to capture just ONE item that's been selected from a listbox, let alone more than one. I particularly don't understand WHEN the items I select are noted by the program because there is no "command" option with a listbox. I think that is so. I don't really understand binding. I think that's my problem (amongst others!).

The following code is extracted from my "app" class.

```
    l = Listbox(self, height=10, selectmode=EXTENDED)
    # Selectmode can be SINGLE, BROWSE, MULTIPLE or EXTENDED. Default BROWSE
    l.grid(column=0, row=11, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

    s = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL, command=l.yview)
    s.grid(column=0, row=11, sticky=(N,S,E))
    l['yscrollcommand'] = s.set

    for i in range(1,101):
        l.insert('end', 'Line %d of 100' % i)

    self.ichoose = l.curselection()
```

As you experts will realise, when I print app.ichoose, I just get an empty tuple.
What do I need to do?
Thanks,
John Rowland

Comment: You'll have to tell us what Scrollbar and Listbox are. What library are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.6 and Tk 8.5 Scrollbar and Listbox are widgets in the Tk library (which of course I have imported).

Comment: that isnt obvious as there are ListBox and Scrollbar in nearly every gui package...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: if you are familiar with Tkinter,  it is very obvious that the code is Tkinter code.

Answer (score 0):

okay... the way I've done this in the past is by:

```
listbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", entered)
```

which then the function `entered` would look something like this:

```
def entered(event):
    global listEx
    items = map(int, listbox.curselection())
    result= listEx[items[0]]
    print result
```

`listEx` is a list of all the entries in the listbox, and the `items = map(int, listbox.curselection())` section will return the index value of the selected entry... if you want to get multiple values, I imagine it would be very simple to for loop through the values in `items`

EDIT:

```
def entered(event):
    print listbox.selection_get()
```

will just print out the selection from the listbox, the reason I like to use my double mouse click is because it is much more likely to be a real world use, normally I use double click and `<Return>` as standard listbox controls, especially if in a use with multiple selections as yours

Comment: You don't need to keep your own copies of the data in the listbox, since the listbox can give you that information.

Comment: you're right sorry, I was just looking through my old scripts, this was the first one I saw, and the reason it used this style was to then use the same index to pull information from a corresponding list.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the item is selected when a user clicks on it, and the default binding fires. If you want to print it out (or do anything else) as soon as possible once that happens, create a binding on the event `<<ListboxSelect>>`. This event will be generated immediately after the selection has changed, even if it changed via the keyboard.